# weird xcodebuild install prompt out of the blue

Tags: macos, install, bug

I ugraded to macOS Monterrey a few days ago. Yesterday, without having done anything, I get this prompt.

[image: xcode build prompt]

The annoying thing is that if I click `Cancel` it just reappears. I didn't ask for this, so I don't want to authorize it. How do I disable it?